# Object constructor from json or xml string

Tags: java, xml, json, constructor

I'm working on a service that spits json everywhere. However one of the providers I consume uses `XML` as serialization format so I want to be able to use the same interface for parsing (and spitting out) `JSON` with that `XML`.

Problem is, I don't know of a `XML` type, or object that would allow me to override my constructor easily. 
Hoping to clarify my point, here's some code:

```
public class JsonData {
    private Hashtable<String, Variant> map = new Hashtable<String, Variant>();

    public JsonData() {
    }

    public JsonData(String jsonString) {
        this.deserialize(jsonString);
    }
```

Ideally I would like a third constructor to do something like:

```
    public JsonData(XMLString jsonString) {
        this.xmldeserialize(jsonString);
    }
```

Note how both relevant constructors take a plain string as argument.

Any pointer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, when you say "override your constructor easily"? The JsonData Factory solution provided by Nikita Beloglazov is an excellent method to create the same type of object, from different types of input. I'm not quite sure why you have what seems to be essentially a wrapper for a HashTable.

If you're looking for libraries to do the XML/JSON serialization/deserialization, I recommend Castor-XML and Jackson respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use static methods to create object from json or xml strings:

```
public static JsonData fromJson(String json) {
    JsonData data = new JsonData();
    data.deserializeJson(json);
    return data;
}

public static JsonData fromXml(String xml) {
    JsonData data = new JsonData();
    data.deserializeXml(xml);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just check if the input is json or xml (using regex) and call appropriate method to deserialize. 
Like

```
public JsonData(String jsonString) {
   if(isValidJson(jsonString){
        this.deserialize(jsonString);
   } else {
        this.xmldeserialize(jsonString);
   }
}
```